# Abstract generic class as generics constraints

Tags: c#, generics, repository, abstract-class

iam trying to create a generic repository for my lookup object and write this:

```
public interface ILookupRepository<T> : 
    IDisposable, 
    ICanGetAll<T>,
    ICanGetById<T, int>
    where T: LookUpObject
{
}
```

`ICan...` are interface that define granular operation for repository, in this way i can use composition to define behaviour

i want to limit this interface only for my LookUp object, so i use the `where T: LookUpObject` constraint

this is the abstract class:

```
public abstract class LookUpObject<TObject, TKeyType> : IKeyedEntity<TKeyType>
    where TObject : class
    where TKeyType : struct
{
    private TKeyType id;
    private string description;
    private bool valid;
    public TKeyType Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description= value; }
    }
    public bool Valid
    {
        get { return valid; }
        set { valid= value; }
    }
    protected LookUpObject()
    {           
    }
}
```

but i don't know how to define constraints on my repo class:
i try

```
public interface ILookupRepository<T> : 
    IDisposable, 
    ICanGetAll<T>,
    ICanGetById<T, int>
    where T: LookUpObject<T1, TkeyType> where T1: class
        where TkeyType: Type
```

but it don't recognize `T1` and `TkeyType`

is it a possible things?

**EDIT**

solution by @Grax with TkeyType instead of int key

```
public interface ILookupRepository<T, TkeyType> : 
    IDisposable, 
    ICanGetAll<T>,
    ICanGetById<T, TkeyType>
    where T : LookUpObject<T, TkeyType>
    where TkeyType : struct
```

Comment: It may just be that `T1` and `TKeyType` need to be on `ILookupRepository`. Not totally sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want this.  This is basically TyCobb's answer with T and T1 combined but I also think you want TKeyType to be struct, based on the constraint you put on your abstract class, rather than for it to literally inherit from Type "Type".

```
    public interface ILookupRepository<T, TKeyType> :
        IDisposable,
        ICanGetAll<T>,
        ICanGetById<T, int>
        where T : LookUpObject<T, TKeyType>
        where TKeyType : struct
    {
    }
```

Now, if your "id" and your "key" are actually the same piece of data, you might even want it this way.  This assumes that the key will be of type "int".

```
    public interface ILookupRepository<T> :
        IDisposable,
        ICanGetAll<T>,
        ICanGetById<T, int>
        where T : LookUpObject<T, int>
    {
    }
```

Comment: guess almost correct, maybe i will transorm ICanGetById<T, int> into ICanGetById<T, TKeyType>. Tomorrow at work i will try and change question code

Answer (score 1):

As Magus stated in the comments, you have to define `T1` and `TKeyType` in the interfaces definition so you can pass in the types.

```
public interface ILookupRepository<T, T1, TkeyType> : 
    IDisposable, 
    ICanGetAll<T>,
    ICanGetById<T, int>
    where T: LookUpObject<T1, TkeyType> where T1: class
        where TkeyType: Type
```

So when you implement the interface, pass in what the types are:

```
public MyPersonRepository : ILookupRepository<Person, MyT1Object, MyType>
```

Your definition may be correct, but looking at what you provided in code, it seems like you are duplicating `T` and `T1`. If this is the case, then get rid of `T1` and just use `T` instead.

Comment: yes: T and T1 are same, I thought i have to redefine thats